# import function from one js file to another js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, error-handling, scrollview

I was trying to import function coz I will want to click on `<il> servies</il>` and scroll to the section services that is in home page
I'm just want to click the li that is on the navbar page and scroll on service section that is on home page. both the pages are different that why is my module not working on NEXT.JS

**Images of code **
[navbar code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PXT5.png)
[serviecs page code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YII6F.png)

**Facing ERROR *

```
Import trace for requested module:
./components/Navbar.js
wait  - compiling...
error - ./components/Navbar.js
Error:
  x Expected ',', got ':'
    ,-[D:\Next.js projects\help-desk\components\Navbar.js:8:1]
  8 |   const ref  = useRef();
  9 |   const scrollToSection = (elementRef) =>{
 10 |     window.scrollTo(
 11 |       top:elementRef.current.offsetTop,
    :          ^
 12 |       behavior: 'smooth'
 13 |     )
 13 |   }
    `----

Caused by:
    Syntax Error

Import trace for requested module:
./components/Navbar.js
```

navbar.js Code:

```jsx
import React from 'react'
import Image from 'next/image'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useRef } from 'react'
import { AiOutlineSearch } from 'react-icons/ai';
AiOutlineSearch
const Navbar = () => {
  const ref  = useRef();
  const scrollToSection = (elementRef) =>{
    window.scrollTo(
      top:elementRef.current.offsetTop,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    )
  }
  return (
    <>
    <div className='flex flex-col md:flex-row md:justify-start justify-center items-center py-1 drop-shadow-xl bg-slate-100'>
    <div className='logo mx-9 cursor-pointer'>
      <Image width={70} height={70} src="/navhome.png" alt=" " />
    </div>
    <div className="nav">
        <ul className='flex items-center space-x-6 font-bold md:text-md'>
          <Link legacyBehavior href={"/"}><a><li>Home</li></a></Link>
          <Link legacyBehavior href={"/about"}><a><li>About</li></a></Link>
          {/* <Link legacyBehavior href={"/servies"}><a><li>Services</li></a></Link> */}
          <li onClick={()=> scrollToSection(ref) href="#section"}>Services</li>
          <Link legacyBehavior href={"/contact"}><a><li>Contact</li></a></Link> 
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="search absolute right-0 top-6 mx-5">
       <AiOutlineSearch className='text-xl  md:text-3xl'/>
      </div>
    </div> 
    </> 
  )
}

export default Navbar;
export { scrollToSection };
```

index.js file:

```jsx
import Image from 'next/image'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Link from 'next/link'
import  {scrollToSection}  from '../components/Navbar.js'
import Servies from '../pages/servies'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>HelpDesk.com - we're here to serve you </title>
        <meta name="description" content="HelpDesk.com - we're here to serve you" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <div>
        <img src="/home.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <section ref={ref} className='scrollService' id='sectionid' >
        <Servies />
        </section>
      <br />
    </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You could try to initialize both of them on one page and then you can use both their functions

Comment: Hello Bilal.

Welcome to stackoverlow.

Please take time to explain what you are wanting to achieve, what you have tried and what is not working.

Add code snipets ONLY for the parts that you need help with.

Be specific.

Comment: thanks for your valuable response but I have a services file and display this on main file but i give the <il> name services and i will just want to when i will click on services il then it will scroll to the services section ...

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired result if you use the id attribute of your section as the target for a link.

```
<section id="section"/>
```

Next.js

```
<Link href="#section"/>
```

React

```
<Link to="#section"/>
```

HTML

```
 <a href="#section">Scroll to section</a>
```

Comment: yes' i will do the same but seeing the same error

Comment: Change 
`<li onClick={()=> scrollToSection(ref) href="#section"}>Services</li>`
 to 
`<Link  href="#services"><li>Services</li></Link>` and make sure the services `<section>` has `id="services"`

Delete 
`const scrollToSection = (elementRef) =>{
    window.scrollTo(
      top:elementRef.current.offsetTop,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    )`